# Как получить данные из переменной интернет страницы с помощью node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, get

Есть интернет страницы. В её исходном коде есть скрипт:

```
<script>
        var important = [{....}];
</script>
```

Как с помощью nodejs получить значения этой переменной?

В похожей ситуации, когда значения было в функции:

```
$(function() {
    _very.important ([{....}]);
```

Я извлекал с помощью:

```
var cloudscraper = require("cloudscraper");    
cloudscraper.get("ссылка" , function(error, response, data) {
      if (error) {
        console.log('ERRRRRRROR');
      } else {
        var info = JSON.parse(data.split("_very.important(")[1].split(")")[0]);
```

Но как поступить в данной ситуации я не знаю. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Вырезать значение переменной JS через регулярку - это приставить полнозаряженный револьвер к виску, нажать на спуск и надеяться что будет осечка. Я бы предложил использовать парсер JS вроде [Acorn](https://github.com/acornjs/acorn) и оттуда извлечь.

Comment: Так тут то же самое, что и раньше просто сначала будет `var important =`, а потом по `;`

Comment: @Other, а где ты тут регулярку увидел?

Comment: @Grundy, я предположил что до неё дойдёт. Просто `split` - детский вариант.

Comment: @Grundy info = JSON.parse(data.split("var important = ")[1].split(";")[0]); ==> TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Comment: @Other И как извлекать с помощью данной библиотеки?

Comment: @RomaRomin, получить код скрипта, скормить его парсеру, посмотреть какое AST он генерирует, взять узел с переменной. Всё.

Comment: @Other Я не понимаю, как мне получить этот самый код скрипта. В этом и весь вопрос. Я не понимаю, как это сделать, вы мне пишите, что мне надо это сделать. Отлично.

Comment: @RomaRomin, взять скрипт можно из парсера HTML, например [Cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio).

Comment: @RomaRomin, точнее пиши по чему разделяешь, ошибся в пробеле и все - получишь один элемент, а не два

Comment: @Other Использую cheerio, он не видит этого скрипта на странице. Много чего находит, но только не этот скрипт.

Comment: @Grundy Каким образом я в том примере могу написать "точнее" ?

Comment: `var $ = require('cheerio')
var parsedHTML = $.load('<html><head><script>let v = 1; // Content</script></head></html>')
console.log( parsedHTML('script').get()[0].children[0].data);`

Comment: @Other И что с этим делать? Я понимаю как распарсить что-то элементарное. Но тут проблема В ДРУГОМ !!! Я даже до этого элемента добраться не могу.

Comment: @RomaRomin, ну Вы посмотрите пример: загружаете код в парсер, ищите там нужный скрипт, берёте его как показано и внутри будет код скрипта. Вот и добрались до элемента.

Comment: Оказывается, этот скрипт виден только авторизованным пользователям, поэтому чтобы я не использовал, я видеть это не буду. Получается, мне нужно научиться авторизоваться на этом сайте?

Comment: Спасибо за попытку помочь. Всем лайк.

Comment: @RomaRomin, Авторизация довольно проста (через `request`, например), главное куки передавать.